# Using tor behind a proxy when just port 80 is open

Tags: proxy, port, tor

I'm wondering if anybody could help me to connect to tor behind a proxy when just port 80 is open.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you scroll down to the "Firewall Ports" option in the Tor manual, you can see that you can set it to "80" and this will only use port 80.

Here is the Tor Manual: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

On Linux this config file, where you can set FirewallPorts among other things, will usually be in /etc/tor/torrc

On Windows, I'm not sure what you would do.

Comment: Also, enable `FascistFirewall`. `If 1, Tor will only create outgoing connections to ORs running on ports that your firewall allows (defaults to 80 and 443; see FirewallPorts)`